# Regex with columns pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, series

My question is how I can use the `re` to replace strings that included in a dataframe:

when I use the `re.sub()`, it gives me an error:

```
p = re.compile('New')
p.sub('old', df['Col1'])
```

Also, I tried using the for loop but the out put was unexpected and displaying the value of the first row in all the other rows:

```
for i in df['Col1']:
    p.sub('old', i)
    print(i)
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), which works also with `regex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['sss old','dd','old']})
print (df)
      Col1
0  sss old
1       dd
2      old

df.Col1 = df.Col1.str.replace('old','new')
print (df)
      Col1
0  sss new
1       dd
2      new
```

Comment: One more question : when i want to use re with the str.startswith. it returns all values false.i.e :   df.col1.str.startswith('(N|n)ew'), am i missing something?

Comment: [str.startswith](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) doesnt work with regex.